# Is Facebook no longer supporting the legacy canvas apps?

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-canvas

I have an app that I wrote a couple years ago that uses Canvas/FBML and relies on fb_sig and other parameters passed to my canvas application.  As of about a week ago, I am only getting the signed_request parameter passed to my application instead of the fb_sig and other variables that used to come for a canvas request.

My application 'edit' page under 'Advanced' shows that there is a Migration feature labeled "signed_request for Canvas", but I have that disabled and am still getting the signed_request parameter for calls to my Canvas/FBML app.

These are the parameters that used to get passed to my app:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/fb_sig/

Does anyone know how I can get this fixed and working with the old code? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah. I got the same problem and updated all of my apps yesterday.

In fact, you need to follow the headlines here: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/534/ and download the latest libraries.

Basic:

```
$fb = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => APP_ID,
      'secret' => APP_SECRET_KEY,
    ));
$user_id = $fb->getUser();
```

And then you need to replace all old facebook calls (like $facebook->api_client) by a call to the "new" Graph API (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/).

You need also to don't longer use the facebook $_POST parameters, like fb_sig_user because they don't exist anymore.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I was hoping there was an easier fix than this, but I feared that would be the answer.  Do you know if there is any way to check for old Facebook client calls, such as $facebook->in_fb_canvas()?

Comment: I don't know for old facebook calls sorry. I only used the $facebook->api_client which is now Graph API.